# Toolbar / CreateToolbarEx problem C++ doesn't display all bitmaps

Tags: c++, bitmap, toolbar

Renders only 4 images with sperator instead of the whole 9 total with 2 separators, no idea what causes it the code looks great.

Here is my code.

```
void CreateMacroToolBar(HWND hDlg)
{
    // Load and register Toolbar control class
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;
    iccx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    iccx.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
    if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&iccx))
        return;

    const DWORD buttonStyles = TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE | TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

    const DWORD TOOLBAR_STYLE = WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS |
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE |
        CCS_NOPARENTALIGN |
        CCS_NORESIZE |
        CCS_NODIVIDER;

    // Declare and initialize local constants.
    const int numButtons = 7;
    const int numButtonsTotal = 9;

    TBBUTTON tbButtons[numButtonsTotal] =
    {
        { 0,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_RECORD, TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Record a macro" },
        { 1,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_STOP,   0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Stop recording" },
        { 2,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_PLAY,   0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Play macro" },
        { I_IMAGENONE,   -1,                      0,               TBSTYLE_SEP,  {0}, 0, -1},  //SEPERATOR
        { 3,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_ERASE,  0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Erase the macro" },
        { 4,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_LOAD,   0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Load a macro" },
        { 5,             IDM_BUTTON_MACRO_SAVE,   0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)(L"Save a macro" },
        { I_IMAGENONE,   -1,                      0,               TBSTYLE_SEP,  {0}, 0, -1},  //SEPERATOR
        { 6,             IDM_MACRO_ABOUTBOX,      TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"About macro options" }
    };
    
    RECT         rect;
    HWND         hwndTB;

    hwndTB = CreateToolbarEx (GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_TOOLBAR_MACRO), //Apply toolbar to static text.
            TOOLBAR_STYLE,                   //Toolbar style.
            ID_MACRO_TOOLBAR,                //Toolbar ID.
            numButtons,                      //Button of buttons (bmp's) (without seperators)
            hDLLModule,                      //Current application instance (where the bitmap is)
            IDR_TOOLBAR_MACRO,               //Bitmap ID.
            tbButtons,                       //Buttons struct
            numButtonsTotal,                 //Total buttons (with seperators)
            16, 15, 16, 15,                  //Button sizes and Bitmap sizes.
            sizeof(TBBUTTON) );

    if (!hwndTB) {
        printf("Loading Macros failed!\n");
        return;
    }

    //SendMessage(hwndTB, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0); //Auto size to show more toolbars TODO: [DOESN'T WORK]
    SendMessage(hwndTB, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0); //Removes the label from Toolbar and adds Tooltips.
}
```

my IDE setup
[image: ide #1]

my toolbar bitmap spliced image looks good
[image: toolbar bitmap #2]

Here is how the bitmap looks in bitmap file .bmp (not the white area isn't accounted for I just did a bad print screen)
[image: toolbar bitmap from file]

Here is how the static text looks like where it gets rendered
[image: rendered static text]

Here is how the static text Properties looks like where the toolbar gets rendered
[image: static text properties]

Finished product when loading looks like this, note it only loads up the first 4 icons + 1 separator total of 5
Instead of 9 as needed with separators, or 7 if it loads only the images
[image: finished product looks like this]

Comment: [ask] suggests introducing the problem before you post any code, rather than starting with your code. *"In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title."* This might be good advice. Personally, I found myself unmotivated to read your code and bored before I reached the end of your question. If others feel the same way, you could be losing valuable potential answerers.

Comment: @JaMiT I added a little summery on top, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A toolbar's height is determined by the height of the buttons, and a toolbar's width is the same as the width of the parent window's client area, also by default. In this case you have passed `GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_TOOLBAR_MACRO)` this is likely the static label. Which would limit the width of the toolbar to the width of that static control. I believe if you pass `hDlg` as the first parameter to `CreateToolbarEx` it will resolve your issue. Or create a new window to contain it that's large enough, who's parent is `hDlg`.

Comment: If that was the case, sadly I doubt it look at this screenshot I posted in the question https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8W50.png the static label width is the size of the whole dialog should be enough to store all of them and then some extra ones

Comment: A toolbar's height is determined by the height of the buttons, and a toolbar's width is the same as the width of the parent window's client area, also by default. I believe you have set the parent window as the static label. So in fact the width is limited by the width of your static window. Try the dialog window as the parent.

Comment: I put it on the main parent window instead of the static label I get the same drawing.. something tells me the problem lies in the `16, 15, 16, 15,`  i'll try setting them to all to `0,0,0,0,` and see if it does a good job automatically calculating it

Comment: Bugger, thought I had it.

Comment: Maybe you do lol, `0,0,0,0,` didn't help same result as well, Yes parent looks the same see here https://i.imgur.com/HVxvTpq.png

Comment: I suggest narrowing the problem down. Determine if clipping is an issue or not. See if the missing icons display correctly if they are the only controls present. That sort of thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225888/discussion-between-jeff-spencer-and-sspoke).

Answer (score 0):

Removing these 2 styles from all buttons fixes the problem.

```
CCS_NOPARENTALIGN | CCS_NORESIZE
```